# Python clear stdout

Tags: python, stdout

I have some kind of web server. It writes log to `sys.stdout` which was redirected to a file. I need to periodically clear this file as it grows. Can I do it using only `sys.stdout`?

Comment: No. Stdout is an output stream. Writing is the only thing you can do to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to delete the logfile:

```
rm logfile
```

or truncate it:

```
echo -n > logfile
```

The webserver will still use the open filedescriptor, and the file will still be on disk, but not reachable by that filename anymore. Once the server restarts (with the same redirection), the logfile will be created from scratch.

Another option would be to use logrotate for your logs, which allows you to change the logfile you are writing to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flush stdout just add this line in your code.

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```